# Get Visual Studio 2010 c++ toolset for Win XP v100_xp

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, visual-c++-2010

Can't find tool set for Win XP for my Visual Studio 2010. Is it still available to download? Where I can get it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it still available for download here:

1. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23507

The Visual Studio 2010 and .NET Framework 4 Training Kit includes presentations, hands-on labs, and demos. This content is designed to help you learn how to utilize the Visual Studio 2010 features and a variety of framework technologies including:

1. C# 4
2. Visual Basic 10
3. F#
4. Parallel Extensions
5. Windows Communication Foundation
6. Windows Workflow
7. Windows Presentation Foundation
8. Silverlight 4
9. ASP.NET 4
10. Windows 7
11. Entity Framework
12. ADO.NET Data Services
13. Managed Extensibility Framework
14. Application Lifecycle Management
15. Windows Azure

**But it requirements are:**

1. Windows 7
2. Windows Server 2008
3. Windows Server 2008 R2
4. Windows Vista
5. Visual Studio 2010 SP1 .NET Framework 4 Silverlight 4

So you may wish to use an older version. Search with this link:

1. https://www.google.com/search?q=visual+studio+2006+download